# Gears and chains

Tags: mountain-bike, gears, hub

How do I know if I can put up a 10speed casette on my 2x8 setup (so can hub support it or do I need a new hub?).

Also can I put a single speed chain on this setup above? I can't seem to find colored chains that "support" 7/8/9 or more speed casettes and chain rings.

Comment: Coloured chains tend to be single speed chain (1/8" width rather than 3/32" derailleur chains)  The colour generally fails quickly when run through a derailleur mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The inner width of derailleur chain is supposed to be the same regardless of number of speeds, so you may get away with using narrower chain. I have been using 9-speed Campagnolo chain with 8-speed Shimano without any problems, but all combinations may not work as well. At worst, the chain could be stuck between chainwheels where it is difficult to remove from.

Single speed chain is wider and stiffer than derailleur chain and will not work with derailleurs.

Answer (score 1):

A 10-speed cassette is spaced narrower than an 8-speed cassette and for that reason will fit onto your free wheel. The problem is that your shifters are indexed for 8 speeds and won't work with a 10-speed cassette. You could make it work if you have downtube shifters that are not indexed or where indexing can be switched off.

The article [Drivetrain Compatibility](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/) has many more details about spacing of cogs and the pull exercised by the shifter.